# Spring boot application how to send multiple response in JSONformate

Tags: java

In button response how to reuse the code i am getting some problem when i response the message every time return the response in if condition , If any solution please explain me 
    package com.kk.springbootrestapp.controller;

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.kk.springbootrestapp.controller.bean.EmployeeBean;
import com.kk.springbootrestapp.controller.response.EmployeeResponse;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "regmep", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody EmployeeResponse registerEmp(@RequestBody EmployeeBean emp) {
        EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();
        try {
            if (!Pattern.matches("^\\S{3,}$", emp.getEname())) {
//`enter code here`
                response.setResponseMessage("Invalid name");
                response.setResposeCode("400");
                return response;
            } else if (!Pattern.matches("^\\S{4,}$", emp.getEjob())) {
                response.setResponseMessage("Invalid job");
                response.setResposeCode("400");
                return response;
            } else if (!Pattern.matches("^[0-9]{2}", emp.getEage().toString())) {
//`enter code here`
                response.setResponseMessage("Invalid age");
                response.setResposeCode("400");
                return response;
            } else {
                response.setResponseMessage("success");
                response.setResposeCode("200");
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            response.setResponseMessage("bad request");
            response.setResposeCode("400");
            return response;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution one**

Quick fix.
You must concat message in your code:

```
EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();
String errorMessage = "";
if (emp == null) {
    responseMessage = "bad request"
} else {
    if (!Pattern.matches("^\\S{3,}$", emp.getEname())) {
        responseMessage += "Invalid name";
    if (!Pattern.matches("^\\S{4,}$", emp.getEjob())) {
        responseMessage += "Invalid job";
    if (!Pattern.matches("^[0-9]{2}", emp.getEage().toString())) {
        responseMessage += "Invalid age";
    }
}
if (StringUtils.isBlank(responseMessage)) {
    response.setResponseMessage("success");
    response.setResposeCode("200");
} else {
    response.setResponseMessage(responseMessage);
    response.setResposeCode("400");
}
return respone;
```

But this is still **ugly code!**

**Solution two.**

You can use [spring validators by annotation](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-validation-for-restful-services-with) and even write your [custom spring validators](https://lmonkiewicz.com/programming/get-noticed-2017/spring-boot-rest-request-validation/).
It's simple to use, but not everything you can do by annotation, there will be situation, you must validate data manually. So you will have validation logic in two places (annotation and validator class), what is confusing when you read old code.

**Solution three.**

Everything in hand written validator. 
Read about **global exception handling** and [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

First of all move this logic to seperate class e.g. `EmployeeBeanValidator`. Instead of use response directly collect data about validation and on the end throw exception e.g. `ValidationException` with list of errors inside. Then you must define exception handler in [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotated class, and there spring modify HTTP.

Comment: Thanks you  for given solution